# Flutter: How to transfer variables when using BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, bottomnavigationview, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have made a BottomNavigationBar with two BottomNavigationBarItem, which can lead to two different pages `HomePage` and `PersonalPage` by clicking. There is a variable named `money` in `PersonalPage`. I wondered that how to transfer `money` from `PersonalPage` to `HomePage` through BottomNavigationBar, or transfer `money` from `PersonalPage` to the controlling page, which contains a `_pageList` containing `HomePage` and `PersonalPage`.
Here are the codes of controlling page:

```
class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  var i = 0;
  String _title = "首页";
  double _barHeight = 60;
  bool _primary = true;
  Color _color = Colors.blue;
  double _elevation = 10;
  var _pageList = [HomePage(), PersonalPage(money: money, key: Key('keyName'))];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_title),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: _elevation,
        toolbarHeight: _barHeight,
        //primary: _primary,
        backgroundColor: _color,

      ),
      //body: this._pageList[this._currentIndex],
      body: IndexedStack(index: _currentIndex, children: _pageList),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              //color: _currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
            ),
            label: "首页",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              //color: _currentIndex == 2 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
            ),
            label: "我的",
          )
        ],
        onTap: (value){
          setState(() {
            this._currentIndex = value.toInt();
            this.i = _currentIndex;
            switch(i){
              case 0: {
                _title = "首页";
                _barHeight = 60;
                _primary = true;
                _color = Colors.blue;
                _elevation = 10;
              } break;
              case 1: {
                _title = "我的";
                _barHeight = 10;
                _primary = false;
                _color = Colors.white70;
                _elevation = 0;
              } break;
            }
          });
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, when creating `PersonalPage`, I will transfer the variable `money` to it. The problem is that how to transfer the changed `money` back.

Thanks for your help. This question maybe quite immature but it is my first Flutter project.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer it:

```
class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
 int curentIndex = 0;
 final GlobalKey<CurvedNavigationBarState> 
 _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final Screen = [
  CourseScreen(),
  RequestScreen(),
  HistoryScreen(),
  NewsScreen(),
  ProfileScreen(),
];

return Scaffold(
    body: Screen[curentIndex],
    bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
      key: _bottomNavigationKey,
      index: curentIndex,
      height: 60.0,
      items: const <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.book, size: 30),
        Icon(Icons.request_page, size: 30),
        Icon(Icons.history_edu, size: 30),
        Icon(Icons.new_label_outlined, size: 30),
        Icon(Icons.account_box, size: 30),
      ],
      color: Colors.white,
      buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      onTap: (index) {
        setState(() {
          curentIndex = index;
        });
      },
      letIndexChange: (index) => true,
    ));
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) state manager for this purpose.

First create money model class:

```dart
class MoneyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  double _value = 00.0 /// This variable holds value of money

  double get value => _value;

  set value(double newValue){
    _value = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then wrap your app with ChangeNotifierProvider:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MoneyModel(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Now MoneyModel (and it's value consequently) is accessible anywhere in your app. You can read (or change) it's value like this:

```dart
/// Read value
Provider.of<MoneyModel>(context).value;
/// Change value
Provider.of<MoneyModel>(context).value = 12.99;
```